# How to make a inline editing colum using ComboBoxCell in GXT and handle his events on a GridEditing?

Tags: gwt, extjs, gxt

I'm new to GXT and I'm trying to do this on 3.0.1 version:

I have a editable grid based in the [showcase example](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:inlineeditablegrid), I have modified the code for the colum that uses the **SimpleComboBox** since i need to handle a value to display and an id just like in normal HTML  and I couldn't find the way of doing this with SimpleComboBox.

Now I'm using **ComboBoxCell** and **ComboBox** to achieve that, but I have two issues.

### issue # 1

When the table displays, the combo column doesn't renders like an inline editing column (like the one in the example).
Here is the code for the column creation: (ObjectDTO just have id and value attributes)

```
public class MyGrid implements IsWidget {

private GridEditing<MyGridDTO> columnEditing;
//another variables needed to create and handle the grid


    public MyGrid(){
    
        List<ColumnConfig<MyGridDTO, ?>> listColumns = new ArrayList<ColumnConfig<MyGridDTO, ?>>();
        sm.setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);
        
        //...
        
        ColumnConfig<MyGridDTO, ObjectDTO> colsomeProperty = new ColumnConfig<MyGridDTO, ObjectDTO>(
                        properties.someProperty(),170,cons.gbsomePropertyTitle());  

        //...               
                
        ComboBoxCell<ObjectDTO> somePropertyCell = new ComboBoxCell<ObjectDTO>(somePropertysStore,new LabelProvider<ObjectDTO>() {
            public String getLabel(ObjectDTO item) {                
                return item.getDescripcion();
            }
            
        });
        
        listColumns.add(colSomeProperty);

        colSomeProperty.setCell(somePropertyCell); 

        final ComboBox<ObjectDTO> combo = new ComboBox<ObjectDTO>(somePropertyCell);

        columnEditing.addEditor(colSomeProperty,combo);
        columnEditing.addBeforeStartEditHandler(new BeforeStartEditHandler<MyGridDTO>() {

                public void onBeforeStartEdit(BeforeStartEditEvent<MyGridDTO> event) {
                    
                    //handle whether or not to allow column editing
                }
            });
    }
        
}
```

it wasn't a big deal until i came into issue #2

### issue # 2

I have to make some of the columns in my grid readonly depending on the row I'm trying to edit. I made this by having a property in MyGridDTO wich is boolean and determines whether or not I can edit this object. The thig is: when editing the comboBox column none of the gridEditingevents rises up, I assume thas behaviour is because of the ComboBox is already visible and not "hidden" behind the inline editing property. I mean, as it is already visible the GridEting is not suposed to handle the edit event any more. Is that possible?

At this point I don't know what to do since i can`t find a workaroud for this. I'm not shure if there is so few information about this out there or if I'm doing my research in a wrong way (most likely)

Any clues?

PD: please apoligize me for my english.

Answer (score 3):

There are three ways to set up a GXT Grid to allow rows to be editable. You seem to be using two of these three methods at once, which is likely the root of issue 1.

The main two ways of allowing a user to edit a row in a grid are [inline-](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3ainlineeditablegrid), and [row-](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3aroweditablegrid)based editing. There are specific examples that describe how to set these up - essentially, you tell the grid just how to draw the data, and then direct the *GridEditing object how to let the user manipulate the data. Both of these tools give additional workflow details (events describing starting/completing/canceling editing), and change the style of a row/cell when it is being modified.

The third option is to directly add cells to the grid. This skips any style or workflow changes, and just lets the user edit the data as is (check out the [cellgrid example](http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace%3acellgrid) for details on what this looks like).

It appears that you are using both the first and third option - you are creating a GridInlineEditing object, and setting it up, but then adding a ComboBoxCell to the ColumnConfig, thus asking the Grid to draw a ComboBox in each cell at all times, even when not editing.

Instead, you probably want just the default behavior (no cell), drawing the value as a string, or a custom AbstractCell subclass that does some specific drawing for your use case.